# WORK PANEL ALONE

Tags: genexus

I am trying to make a small application that is composed of a workpanel that has a grid with data from a table in sqlserver. This application runs alone on one side of the screen as an .EXE. How can I do so that only the work panel is shown and nothing else, without the developer menu or just the sale of the work panel?
I am using GENEXUS EVO2.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is really quite broad. It is really necessary for you to be more specific with your problem. Also, if you have any code, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Just mark that workpanel as main: MainProgram = True